# Unable to preview Google rich results in the testing tool

Tags: seo, google-search-console, rich-snippets, google-rich-snippets-tool

I'm new to Google rich results, I'm playing around with the [Article](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/article) Example, when I test it out in the Rich Results Test , the Preview Results button is disabled, am I missing something to have it enabled?

[image: Preview Results button grey out]

Notice how the Preview Results button is grayed out, why is that? There is no error anywhere

Comment: The schema you are showing in the image is an "@type" : "Article" ,,, their is no rich snippet in search for that type of schema. It just looks normal in search.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I got the answer. the preview tool will not always let you preview any Rich Result. Especially for search, the tool will craw your page and internally decide if your page is eligible for the search Rich Result. if it deems your page is not eligible you won't be able to preview it, regardless if you have the Rich Result setup correctly

Answer (score 1):

Per Google Search Console [help article](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7445569?hl=en#:%7E:text=For%20some%20rich%20result%20types,for%20desktop%20and%20mobile%20searches.):

> See how your page might look in Google Search results
> For some rich result types you can preview how the result might appear in Google Search or Google Assistant. If your page is eligible for multiple Search result layouts, this tool will include selectors to let you view the different layouts, including layouts for desktop and mobile searches.

I suspect there might be different kinds of rich text / schema that you could leverage that might activate that option. Personally, I don't think I have ever seen it active but it could be that I have never used the type of schema necessary.

Google has a list of supported types in their [documentation](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9012289#rich_results) (under Enhancements (AMP, rich results) accordion.